# Multiple OR conditions relating to value of a parameter

Tags: vba, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I have an SSRS report that I'm working on that returns multiple rows and columns of data.

I would like to have a parameter that allows the user to enter a value for the data to be filtered on.
The catch is that this parameters value may be in any one of multiple columns.

I was hoping to use a filter expression that utilities multiple OR conditions.

[image: screenshot of filter setup]

The expression I have currently (that isn't working) is:

```
=IIf(Fields!Call_ID.Value = Parameters!SearchFor.Value)
or(Fields!Surname.Value = Parameters!SearchFor.Value) 
or (Fields!Mobile.Value = Parameters!SearchFor.Value) 
or (Fields!Land_Tel.Value = Parameters!SearchFor.Value) 
or (Fields!Email.Value = Parameters!SearchFor.Value) 
or (Fields!Postcode.Value = Parameters!SearchFor.Value) 
or (Fields!Product_Class.Value = Parameters!SearchFor.Value) 
or (Fields!Referral_Authorisation_Number.Value = Parameters!SearchFor.Value ), "Include", "Exclude")
```

Any help would be gratefully received.

Thanks

Comment: Is this a typo or are you missing one parenthesis at the beginning of the iif statement... it should be ```=IIF((``` in your case...

Comment: Yes...typo on my part and once inserted, resolves the issue.

I'll be over in the corner of shame if anybody needs me,

Thanks